# Create a friendly error page for failed signins using AzureAD and Authentication.AzureAD.UI: AADSTS50105

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I am using AzureAD as a login provider for a .net core 3.1 app, using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI nuget package, and it is all set up and working.

AzureAD only allows users from the tenant access, if the user is not in the tenant then it shows them a sensible error page.

If a user has access to the site but needs a specific role to view a page they get redirected to /Account/AccessDenied/ page.

However if the user has no role assigned but is in the tenant, azure ad does a POST to my site's /signin-oidc/ with the following POST body:

```
error: interaction_required
error_description: AADSTS50105: The signed in user '{EmailHidden}' is not assigned to a role for the application
error_uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=50105
```

My site then responds with a 405 method not allowed error.

I would like to handle this POST and provide a friendly error page saying the user needs to request access.

Settings defined in startup.cs already:

ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAzureAD(options =>
    {
        configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
    });

services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(AzureADDefaults.CookieScheme,
    options => options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied");

services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
{
    options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";

    // add name to User.Identity
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        NameClaimType = "name"
    };

    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = true;
});

services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    // require user is logged in and has predefined role in order to access anything
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .RequireRole("Role1", "Role2")
            .Build();

    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
})
```

Configure:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Have seen the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63730182/how-to-navigate-to-custom-access-denied-page-when-ad-authentication-failed-for-u) but it seems as if I have already done what it suggests and it's not working.

My thoughts are that it never even reaches the AuthorizeFilter I've set up as AzureAD.UI just fails to handle the POST to singin-oidc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an Event for your OpenIdConfiguration that will redirect to the proper page on some specific error from Azure.

```
options.Events.OnMessageReceived = async context =>
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.ProtocolMessage.Error) &&
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.ProtocolMessage.ErrorDescription) &&
                context.ProtocolMessage.ErrorDescription.StartsWith("AADSTS50105"))
        {
        context.Response.Redirect("/Account/AccessRequest/");
        context.HandleResponse();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```